InvalidCastException with EnvDTE.DTE but only on some machines?
I have this code to start an instance of TwinCAT (which is basically VisualStudio) and get its DTE interface.
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("TcXaeShell.DTE.15.0");
if (t == null) return null;
DTE dte = null;
dte = (DTE)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
return dte;

On my PC I have no problem running this code. Some of my colleagues however, get this Exception:
The COM object of type "System. __ComObject" cannot be converted to the interface type "EnvDTE. DTE". This operation could not be performed because the QueryInterface call to the COM component for the interface with the IID "-33250A8D-7E1F-3EEA-9D72-A013AE97D9EC" could not be performed due to the following error: Interface not supported (exception of HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
Clearly the cast to DTE is problematic, so I modified the code as follows:
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("TcXaeShell.DTE.15.0");
if (t == null) return null;
DTE dte = null;
try
{
    dte = (DTE)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
}
catch (InvalidCastException)
{
    string installPath = getTcInstallPath();
    if (installPath == null) return null;;
    if (!File.Exists(installPath)) return null;
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(installPath);
    int timeout = 200;
    while (dte == null && timeout > 0)
    {
        timeout--;
        List<DTE> dtes = getComObjectsFromId(proc.Id);
        dte = (dtes.Count > 0) ? dtes.First() : null;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
return dte;

private static List<DTE> getComObjectsFromId(int processId)
{
    List<DTE> results = new List<DTE>();
    // get list of windows processes
    IRunningObjectTable runningObjectTable;
    GetRunningObjectTable(0, out runningObjectTable);

    // get enumerator for the list
    runningObjectTable.EnumRunning(out IEnumMoniker monikerEnumerator);
    monikerEnumerator.Reset();

    // iterate over list and crate a subset with fitting processes
    IMoniker[] monikers = new IMoniker[1];
    // as long as there is 1 more process to iterate over, that process can be accessed through monikers[0]
    while (monikerEnumerator.Next(1, monikers, IntPtr.Zero) == 0)
    {
        CreateBindCtx(0, out IBindCtx ctx);
        monikers[0].GetDisplayName(ctx, null, out string runningObjectName);
        if (!runningObjectName.EndsWith(processId.ToString())) continue;
        runningObjectTable.GetObject(monikers[0], out dynamic runningObjectData);
        try { results.Add((DTE)runningObjectData); }
        catch { continue; }
    }
    return results;
}

As you can see I am now starting TwinCAT manually from its .exe and then searching through the runningObjectTable to find the process again. I realized there are multiple objects connected to one processId therefore I'm trying to cast each one to DTE and return a list of all successes.
During testing I found out, that on my PC this List contains exactly one element. On my colleagues PC it doesn't contain any elements.
So here's the question:
Where does this dependency of not being able to cast to DTE stem from? Could it be that VisualStudio is installed locally on m colleagues PC but system wide on mine and therefore the registry entry that GetTypeFromProgID would find is in a different place? But then why doesn't the casting work after finding the corresponding COM_object.
